# Is there an equivalent reading to Russel's 'The Problems of Philosophy' but for metaphysics?

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request, ontology

I'm looking for an overview of the field of metaphysics accessible to laymen. If there is anything that leans in any way towards the social sciences, I would be particularly interested in it.

Comment: Introductory level? Maybe Michael Rea, Metaphysics: The Basics (Routledge, 2014), AW Moore, The Evolution of Modern Metaphysics: Making Sense of Things (Cambridge University Press, 2011), Michael Loux, Metaphysics: A Contemporary Introduction (Routledge, 1998)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA sure, why not; I wouldn't mind for suggestions at different levels of competence

Comment: [Metaphysics: The Key Concepts](https://www.amazon.com/Metaphysics-Key-Concepts-Routledge-Guides/dp/0415559286) is brief and modern, [Lindsay, The fundamental problems of metaphysics](https://archive.org/details/fundamentalprobl00lindrich/page/n7/mode/2up) if you want it from the same time period as Russell's, also free. [Calkins, The persistent problems of philosophy; an introduction to metaphysics](https://archive.org/details/persistentproble00calkrich/mode/2up), same but longer.

Comment: You can try Aristotles *Metaphysics* which started the whole tradition and is actually quite readable especially with an introduction that places it in context ...